# Retrieving JSON data in controller from URL with cakephp

Tags: php, json, cakephp, knockout.js

I'm trying to pass JSON encoded data from Knockout.js to an action in my controller but it's not working and showing as null.

I used the same script in a non-cake php file and it worked perfectly. Is there a special way to decode json data with cake? Say this is the URL being passed.

```
/orders/submit_order/%7B"orderInfo":["itemNumber":"1","quantity":"1","price":"1.00","productName":"Test Product"]%7D
```

Here is the action

```
//OrdersController

function submit_order($order = null){
    $order = json_decode($order, true); 
    print_r($order);
   //I also tried commenting out the json decode to simply pass the info without further processing but that just displayed "t"

}
```

Is there a special way to handle this with Cakephp? With a standard php file I'd set something like

```
 page.php?order=....json data
```

And then access it with

```
$order = $_GET['order'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try sending the data via POST instead of GET?  It is possible that the array notation in the url is not being escaped correctly.

Comment: I'm attempting to do this, but I'm having some issues. I made a post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600426/post-data-from-knockout-js-to-cakephp-controller) mind taking a look?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending the data as a regular query string and then accessing it as your would any normal string in your controller?

Check out [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) which should allow you to turn a json object into a query string. Here is the example from the page:

```
var myObject = {
  a: {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3
  },
  b: [1,2,3]
};
var recursiveEncoded = $.param(myObject);
var recursiveDecoded = decodeURIComponent($.param(myObject));

alert(recursiveEncoded);
alert(recursiveDecoded);
```

and the results (respectively for each function called):

```
a%5Bone%5D=1&a%5Btwo%5D=2&a%5Bthree%5D=3&b%5B%5D=1&b%5B%5D=2&b%5B%5D=3 
a[one]=1&a[two]=2&a[three]=3&b[]=1&b[]=2&b[]=3
```

Comment: How am I supposed to decode the value since I'm retrieving it from my CakePHP controller and not in JavaScript?